# Postgres function - can it return a type AND/OR a setof type?

Tags: postgresql

I would like to write a PLPGSQL function for postres that returns a complex type on success, and a SETOF some other complex type on failure.  Is that possible?

I have considered returning an array of the type on failure, but the array could potentially contain tens of thousands of entries, so I am assuming it would be unwise to return it as an array.  Is that a correct assumption?

Comment: Out of interest - why?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by returning a record of a cursor and a complex type like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION example(IN integer, INOUT refcursor, OUT boolean, OUT point) AS $$
BEGIN
    IF 0 = $1 THEN                          -- Dummy condition
        OPEN $2 FOR SELECT * FROM pg_class; -- Open the given cursor for some query.
        $3 := true;                         -- Indicate that the operation was successful.
    ELSE
        $4 := point(1, 2);                  -- Return a composite type.
        $3 := false;
    END IF;
END;
$$ STABLE LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Use like this:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT example(0, 'my_cursor');
-- Check the value of the first output parameter.
FETCH ALL IN 'my_cursor';
COMMIT;
```

I don't think it will be very convenient, though. If the contents of the cursor can't be fetched from a view or a table, you need to have another function that assumes that the operation succeeds. Also having a branch that handles either a set of rows or a single value won't be easy to write in SQL.